# Redirect custom domain path to Cloudfront AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

So I have a simple rating page hosted as a static website on a S3 bucket (deployed from GitHub with Code-Pipeline). I've also created a CloudFront distribution to speed up the website.

Let's say my domain is `example.com`, how can I redirect my CloudFront distribution to something like `example.com/path` - where path is a new resource in my domain.

All the solutions I came to indicated me to create a hosted zone and an alias to the distribution with Route53, but that would only create a subdomain - like `path.example.com`, is it possible to redirect to a new path resource in my domain?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a **redirect**, you can use CloudFront Functions to redirect at the edge. Example (just ignore the country checks):
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/redirect-based-on-country

If you want a **url rewrite**, there are two options:

- If you want a request to CloudFront of `example.com/foo` to fetch `your-origin.com/path/foo` from your origin, edit the **Origin path** field on your origin in the CloudFront console to `/path`
- If you want a conditional URL rewrite, you can use CloudFront functions to rewrite the `request.uri` as needed. Example:  https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps